# If p is an odd prime, prove that for all $r \geq 1$, one has $\phi(p^r) \geq \sqrt {p^r}$, and prove that for $r \geq 2$, $\phi(2^r) \geq \sqrt{2^r} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If p is an odd prime, prove that for all $r \geq 1$, one has $$\phi(p^r) \geq \sqrt {p^r}$$ and prove that for $r \geq 2$ $$\phi(2^r) \geq \sqrt{2^r} $$

I'm stuck on both of these, I tried induction on the second one, but it didn't work because eulers phi function doesn't work with non co-primes. I'm supposed to use these two proofs to deduce $$\phi(n) \geq \sqrt{n/2}$$ for all $n\geq1$

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should know that $\varphi ( p^r)= p^{r-1}(p-1)$.

Comment: would it be possible to prove both of these via induction with that?

Comment: Well, it's much easier: note that both $p$ and $p-1$ are strictly larger than $\sqrt{p}$. Hence $$p \cdots p \cdot (p-1) > \sqrt{p} \cdots \sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt{p}$$

Comment: what do the 3 dots mean between p's?

Comment: All you have to prove is that $\varphi(p^r) = p^r - p^{r-1}$ since $p^r - p^{r-1} \ge 2 p^{r-1} > p^{r/2}$

Comment: @user1952009 that completely confused me, I don't understand where the right hand side of that entire equation came from

Comment: there are $p^{r-1}$ integers in $1 \ldots p^{r}$ that are divisble by $p$. The others are coprime to $p$ and $p^r$

Comment: thanks, that helped put me on the right track I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\phi(p^r)=p^{r-1}(p-1)$ and $\sqrt{p^r}=p^{r/2}$, so certainly we have $\phi(p^r)\geq \sqrt{p^r}$ if $r-1\geq r/2$, which is equivalent to $r\geq 2$. This works equally for $p$ odd or equal to 2.

So the only thing left to show is that $\phi(p)=p-1\geq\sqrt{p}\textrm{ }$   for $p$ an odd prime. In particular, that means $p$ is at least 3, which is all you need. You can prove this inequality in various ways - for example, square both sides and factor the resulting quadratic. I would simply note that the inequality holds for $p=3$ by computation and that the derivative of $x-1-\sqrt{x}$ is strictly positive for $x>1$.

Comment: thank you! I followed your advice and ended up with $3+/- \sqrt{5}$ all over 2, which is of course greater than 0.